# where is /data/preload folder on my [rooted] android phone?

Tags: files

I need to copy a file into this folder.
I cannot find this folder using the root explorer. Where is it?
I know it exists (or should exist) since system gives me an error message saying that file is missing in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

You must have Root rights. It's in Root\Preload.

Comment: thanks @dfa for the reply. yes it is rooted. But, this is such an old post. I do not need it anymore. Just if you are curios, in the end I could not find a solution for this question.